# Passing an instance of an interface from a Service to an AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Title says it all really, I am struggling to send a instance of my interface to an asynctask

Service:

```
 public class CompletedPicks extends Service implements AsyncResponseForCompletedPick {

PickList p;
Context ctx;


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Context _ctx)
{
    this.ctx = _ctx;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
            for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
                if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                    if (ni.isConnected())
                        haveConnectedWifi = true;
            }

            if (haveConnectedWifi)
            {
                PickListTableOps PLTO = new PickListTableOps(getBaseContext());
                List<PickList> myList = PLTO.GetItemsReadyForUpload();

                if(myList.size() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++)
                    {
                        p = myList.get(i);

                        int result = new CompletedPick(getBaseContext(),this ,p);


                    }
                }
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
        }
    }, 10000);
}

@Override
public void returnsuccess(Integer integer, PickList p) {

    PickListTableOps PLTO = new PickListTableOps(getBaseContext());
    PLTO.UpdateSentStatus(this.p.getPicklist_id(), this.p.getSku_id());

}
```

Task:

```
public myTask(Context ctx, myInterface in, PickList p)
```

I have tried an instance of Context and myservice.this but cannot work out what reference I need to send.

This is a Service and not an IntentService so httprequests (which is what my AsyncTask handles) need to be done on a seperate thread

Thanks

Comment: do you have a class that implements `myInterface` ?

Comment: pass getApplicationContext() refereence to that constructor

Comment: @blackbelt - yes, myservice implements myInterface

Comment: @santhosh - Sorry, this doesn't work either

Comment: then you should wrote `this` new myTask(getBaseContext(), this, p), if you are running it in the setvice

Comment: @blackbelt, nope doesn't work = Expected - Parameters, Actual - Argument, same as getBaseContext, MyService.this

Comment: can you post more code?

Comment: you miss the PickList, I can not see declared anywhere. And also a semicolumn

Comment: pseudo code! The rest is irrelevant, but I have added it all jjust in case

Comment: is `CompletedPick` the AsyncTask?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, amatuer error, I have two closely named tasks!

this does it:

```
new CompletedPick(getBaseContext(),CompletedPicks.this ,p).execute();
```